# OpenVPN - Forwarding only IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu server, and a Windows 8 desktop. The server has IPv6 connectivity, but the desktop does not, so is there a way using OpenVPN to ONLY forward IPv6 traffic to the VPN, and leave all my other traffic as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

Don't configure any `route` options client-side, or `push "route ..."` options server-side; only add routes for IPv6 subnets (using `route-ipv6`).  Then, only IPv6 traffic will be routed over the VPN.

If you want to route all the IPv6 traffic over the VPN, push a default route (`::/0`).  Otherwise, push whatever routes you otherwise would.

You probably already know that you need to use the ipv6 variants of stuff as well (`tun-ipv6`, `ifconfig-ipv6`, etc.).